# How to echo a multiple line text file (batch)

Tags: batch-file

I need to echo a text file with multiple lines.
Here's what I've done, but this only echo's the first line.

```
set /p errorlog=<errorlog.txt
echo %errorlog%
pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include the entire file, and don't really need the environment variable, why not type the file?

```
type errorlog.txt
```

Environment variables are not intended to hold the entire contents of the file, and cannot store newlines as values. The value will terminate at the first newline.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be stored as a variable at one point, try:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%G in (errorlog.txt) do (
    echo %%G
)
```

Note that this method can allow you to only echo part of a file if you include a count function, but is slower the longer `errorlog.txt` is.